# How to use Jquery plug in Multi File upload on Dynamically added File input box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi I am using Jquery plug in jquery.MultiFile.pack.js . usage of this plug in requires input form element to be of class "multi"

```
<input id="preview" class="multi" name="preview[]" type="file" />
```

I am adding form elements dynamically from a PHP script. Multi file upload is not working when the elements are added dynamically, but works when element is allready present directly in the  .

My question is how do I make this multi file upload to work. I tried to add class "multi" to the elements usng "on" as below, but it is not working.

```
$('input:file').on('click',function(){
  $('#preview').addClass("multi");

});
```

Comment: When you ask something, please add related code and other relevant information such as which plugin, link to the plugin documentation etc.

Answer (score 0):

For an HTML file input to accept a multiple file selection, you have to add it the `multiple` property :

```
<input id="preview" class="multi" name="preview[]" type="file" multiple/>
```

Comment: Is this multiple property part of HTML5?. So if I use multiple property I do not need to use any additional plugins.

Comment: Yes it's an HTML5 property and it's supported by all major browsers. If you just need to have multiple file to upload in a form, then it's the best solution !

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working for me. I am using jquery to submit the form and load the result on to a div. Will jquery serializeArray() handle this multiple property?.

Comment: Do you just submit the form or do you send it by ajax ? if it's by ajax, you mus do some tweaking to your ajax request to be able to send files : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8758614/4734683